# c++ template member function specialization based on parameter value

Tags: c++, templates, type-deduction

I try to simplify c++ code in quite large old c++ project solving following simple example would help me apply the pattern to the code I work with. The code is quite large And I simplified it to the core problem.

I would like to write c++ template code which can deduce template type in compile time based on argument (for example enum). In my current code I have to write template type by hand

```
GetSignal<int*>(Signals::Clear)
```

which can be error prone. I would like to implement SomeMagicNeedToBeHere to cause the expected behaviour.

```
enum Signals{ Clear, Filtered};


template <class DATA> class ContainerClass 
    : public SomeMagicNeedToBeHere<int*,Signals::Clear>,
      public SomeMagicNeedToBeHere<float*,Signals::Filtered>
{
   void DoSomething()
   {
        //auto == int*
        auto clear = GetSignal(Signals::Clear);

        //auto == float*
        auto filtered = GetSignal(Signals::Filtered);

   }
};
```

It is possible to deduce the type based on argument value and how?

UPDATE (rewrite the example):

I have checked the old code and my example was not right, there was no base class for typed being deduced. I have changed the fruit to int and float for better understanding.

Comment: You can deduce template based on argument value but only at compile time. Perhaps you could add more details to your requirements.

Comment: Why not just have a `GetFruit` function which returns a `FruitBase` pointer, and creates the correct instance (`MyApple` or `MyBanana`) depending on the argument in a simple `if` or `switch` statement? Don't over-complicate things.

Comment: That is the situation I have now, but I need to cast it manually.

Comment: Or just use the template type, and skip the enumeration?

Comment: If `FruitBase` contains proper virtual member functions that are overridden in the child classes, why would you need to cast? Seems like we have a case of [the XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you tell us of a solution you want help fixing, but you don't really tell us what *problem* you're trying to solve. There may be other solutions to your problem.

Comment: what is `GetSignal` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following may help:

```
// helper to get some type depending of signal
template <Signals sig> struct helper;

// specialization for each Signal to get type
template <>
struct helper<Clear>
{
    using type = int*;
};

template <>
struct helper<Filtered>
{
    using type = float*;
};

// And you may do similar stuff with function (and be generic if the type helper is enough)
template <Signals sig>
typename helper<sig>::type GetSignal()
{
    return nullptr;
}
```